# CSS change triggered by react-router-dom changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am creating a small site using create-react-app with sass and want to be able to change the Navbar.Brand styling, including hiding it when the home page is visible, based on the url path.

I am assuming an IF statement can be used but cannot find a way to identify or trigger the change based on the react-router-dom path change.

Is this even possible? if so how?

Comment: so I have answered the question of identifying the URL and written a function to add a classname but is doesn't add the classname or throw an error. `function Brand() {
    let brand = document.getElementById('Brand')
    // let brand = document.querySelector('#Brand')
    let scope = window.location.href

    if (scope === 'http//localhost:3000/') {
        brand.setAttribute("className", "d-none")
    } else {

    if (scope === 'http//localhost:3000/test') {
        brand.setAttribute("className", "Pink")
    } else
        console.error(scope);
    }
}

Brand();`

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work quite nicely by using the componentDidMount function.

```
    componentDidMount(){
    let brand = document.getElementById('Brand')
    brand.setAttribute('class', 'd-none')
    let nav = document.getElementById('Nav')
    nav.setAttribute('class', 'd-none')
}
```

This gives me the ability choose what shows on other react components when a specific page or component is loaded. It needs to be within the class x extends Component {} code block.